# How can I create a thread that returns the results to multiple activities simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, background

I need help! I'm developing an app consists of two activity where the first activity starts the second. I need to run a thread exclusively in the second activity, which reads data from a server and displays them in the first activity and in the second. Specifically, if I have a situation where during the execution of the thread in the second activity, I press the back button to return to the first activity, the same thread must continue its execution without suspend him or lock up and give me back the real-time results that I can see in both activity.

Do you have any suggestions for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's what Service is for.  A Service can be started by the second Activity, but will exist even after the death of that Activity.  The Thread should be owned by the service.  The service can send a broadcast with the results, which both the first and second activities can listen for.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example?Thanks.